# How to generate control from control name in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sub that recive a control name in argument as string and I want to convert the name to a control
I tried this sub :

```
Public Sub text_initialize(ByVal CurrentPage As String)
    Dim ctrl As Control
    For Each ctrl In UserForm1.MultiPage1.Controls(CurrentPage).Controls
        'some code here
    Next ctrl
End Sub
```

and in the call I did this :

```
text_initialize "Page1"
```

I found that solution "Controls(CurrentPage)" mentioned for textboxs but it dosen't seem to works for pages !

And if there is any other way to pass page as argument so that I can modify all controls on it I would like to know .

Comment: Just a gut feeling, are you sure the page is named `page1` and not `Page1`?

Comment: Also, I think you need [`Pages`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/page-object-pages-collection-multipage-control-selecteditem-property-example) and not `Controls`

Comment: @CherryDT yes thank's it is `Page1` I just edit it but that didn't solve the problem

Comment: @CherryDT thank you very much, I use  `Pages` instead of `Controls` as you recommend .
And I had also  to replace `MultiPage1` by `UserForm1.MultiPage1`,and now it works. **thank you** again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank's to @CherryDT he found two mistakes in my code the first that I should use `Page1` instead of `page1`and `Pages` instead of `Controls`
and I found out that for some reason I had to replace `MultiPage1` by `UserForm1.MultiPage1`
so the correct code now is :

```
Public Sub text_initialize(ByVal CurrentPage As String)
    Dim ctrl As Control
    For Each ctrl In UserForm1.MultiPage1.Controls(CurrentPage).Controls
        'some code here
    Next ctrl
End Sub
```

And call it like that :

```
text_initialize "Page1"
```